# Add SCNNode after rotating rootNode

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm trying to add a node (a sphere) to a body model but it doesn't work properly after I rotate the model through a pan gesture.

Here's how I'm adding the node (using a long tap gesture):

```
func addSphere(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch sender.state {
    case .Began:
        let location = sender.locationInView(bodyView)
        let hitResults = bodyView.hitTest(location, options: nil)

        if hitResults.count > 0 {
            let result = hitResults.first!

            let secondSphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.015)                
            secondSphereGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.redColor()

            let secondSphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: secondSphereGeometry)

            let vpWithZ = SCNVector3(x: Float(result.worldCoordinates.x), y: Float(result.worldCoordinates.y), z: Float( result.worldCoordinates.z))

            secondSphereNode.position = vpWithZ

            bodyView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(secondSphereNode)
        }

        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Here is how I rotate the view:

```
func rotateGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = sender.translationInView(sender.view)

    var newZAngle = (Float)(translation.x)*(Float)(M_PI)/180.0
    newZAngle += currentZAngle

    bodyView.scene!.rootNode.transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(newZAngle, 0, 0, 1)

    if sender.state == .Ended {
        currentZAngle = newZAngle
    }
}
```

And to load the 3D model I just do:

```
bodyView.scene = SCNScene(named: "male_body.dae") // bodyView is a SCNView in the storyboard
```

I found something related to the `worldTransform` property and also the function `convertPosition:toNode:` but couldn't find an example that works well.

The problem is that, if I rotate the model, the sphere are not positioned properly. They're always positioned as if the model was in its initial state.

[image]

If I turn the body and add long tap his arm (on the side), the sphere is added somewhere floating in front of the body, as you can see above.

I don't know how to fix this. Appreciate if someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Where do you want the sphere to appear instead?

Comment: @HalMueller on the surface of the body model. If I add the sphere while the body is in its initial position (front), the spheres are positioned on the surface.

Comment: IIRC, assigning to `rootNode.transform` will get you a console message about not transforming the root node. Heed that warning — add a container mode for your content if you have to, and transform that instead.